# Recognizing EOF vs newline in getline in C

Tags: c, newline, eof, getline

is there any way how to recognize if getline was ended because of newline or because of EOF?

So, I would like to distinguish:

1.
**alfa \n beta \n gama \n EOF**

2.
**alfa \n beta \n gama EOF**

In the second case I don't want to read gama as a new string and I want to say, that the reading of last string was not successful. I am using while cycle to read the lines.

I can't edit incoming data.

There is probably possibility to solve this by using getchar. However it makes reading lines more complicated :-/

Thank you so much

Comment: You can use the `feof` function to test for `EOF` on a stream, but it won't return `true` until *after* you try to read past the end of file.

Comment: read next character with fgetc, check if its EOF, if not put it back with ungetc.

Comment: I'm not sure why you can't just use `getline`. In both cases, you'll get the lines back one-at-a-time. On EOF, the return value will be -1. But, you won't get that until the _fourth_ call. In the first case, the return sequence will be: `5,5,5,-1` and in the second, it will be: `5,5,4,-1` Only the _last_ line _can_ be different and you can look at: `buf[len - 1] == '\n'`. There's no way to simultaneously get a non-zero length _and_ EOF indication in the same call.

Answer (score 5):

Like `fgets()`, `getline()` includes the trailing newline in the string. So just check the last character after a successful call to see if it's a `'\n'`. If it's something else, you have the last line of a file without a trailing newline.

Comment: Checking the last character deserves detail.  With `getline()`, easy to code wrong considering a -1 return or reading null characters.  `fgets()` has additional cases that make  checking the last character problematic.

Answer (score 3):

> is there any way how to recognize if getline was ended because of newline or because of EOF?

If the line input stopped due to end-of-file, `feof()` returns true.

```
ssize_t nread = getline(&line, &len, stream);
if (feof(stream)) {
  puts("Input ended due to end-of-file");
}
if (nread > 0 && line[nread-1] == '\n') {
  puts("Input ended due to end-of-line");
}
```

It is possible for both to be false: input error or allocation failure.

---

Concerning `fgets()`, additional issues occur when the buffer is full or a null character was read.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your tips.

Finally I used easier way how to do it.

`characters = getline(&line, &len, stream);`

`if (characters==-1) {puts("Input ended by EOF after \n");}`

`if (feof(stdin)) {puts("Input ended by just EOF");}`

Comment: After reading some input and then end-of-file occurs, `getline()` does not return -1. 
There are at least 4 reasons why `getline()` returns -1.  Encounters `EOF` after no other input is 1 of them.